# How can I send mail to more than one recipient

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-mail

I have an HTML form where user can enter more than one mail id, but I don't know how can I send mail to more than one person

I am successfully sending mail to one user, but here I am stuck in sending more than one email.

**What I've done:**

This is my `EmailUntility` class:

```
public class EmailUtility {
public static void sendEmail(String host, String port, final String userName, final String password,
        String toAddress, String subject, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {


    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    });
    session.setDebug(false);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(message);

    Transport.send(msg);

}
```

}

And this one is my Servlet doPost

```
        String recipient = request.getParameter("email-ids");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    System.out.println(recipient);

    try {
        EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, recipient, subject,
                content);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

When I am printing `recipient` on console I am getting mail ids from UI as `abc@gmail.com,efg@gmail.com,123@gmail.com` all the three are with `,` seperator

This one is working fine when there is only one recipient but when there are more than one I don't know how to do that

I am using `java.mail` api for sending mails.

Comment: You already have `InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };` to adding another address shouldn't be a problem. Is you actual problem that you get a string like `abc@gmail.com,efg@gmail.com,123@gmail.com` and need to split that into multiple addresses? If so, do you want to allow that at all? If yes, what did you try to split that input so far?

Comment: @Thomas i want to allow it to send multiple address i am already getting string with `,` seperator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `toAddress` is string which consists email ids separated by `,`

```
if (toAddress!= null) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    if (toAddress.contains(",")) {
        emails.addAll(Arrays.asList(toAddress.split(",")));
    } else {
        emails.add(toAddress);
    }
    Address[] to = new Address[emails.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    for(String email : emails) {
        to[counter] = new InternetAddress(email.trim());
        counter++;
    }
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
}
```

Comment: sir `message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);` this one is showing error   `The method setRecipients(Message.RecipientType, Address[]) is undefined for the type String`

Comment: `void javax.mail.Message.setRecipients(RecipientType type, Address[] addresses)`  takes the address and `to``is of address type

Comment: sir i am getting errors can you edit your code with mine one so that i can understand what am i doing wrong,please

Comment: I can do that but issue will be I can debug of test the code. The code which I wrote is kind of tested

Answer (score 1):

From your description I assume the parameter `email-ids` can have multiple values. Hence `String recipient = request.getParameter("email-ids");` is wrong.

I'll cite the [Javadoc on `ServletRequest.getParamter(String)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) (emphasis by me):

> You should only use this method when you are *sure* the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use `getParameterValues`.

So it should be `String[] recipients = request.getParameterValues("email-ids");` instead. (You *could* also try to split the single string you get with your code but if you already get multiple values then concatenating and splitting them again just feeld wrong and risky.)

With those individual strings it should then be no problem to create multiple elements for the array `InternetAddress[] toAddresses` you are already using.

Comment: hey i used `getParameterValues` but my java class throws error this one is throwing error `EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, recipients, subject,
                    content);`  and error is  `The method sendEmail(String, String, String, String, String, String, String) in the type EmailUtility is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String[], String, String)`

Comment: @viveksingh yes that's because you you can't send an array when a single `String` is expected. I assumed you'd realize that you need to change your method's signature as well.

Comment: So what should be my message signature i have posted my `EmailUtility` class

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be a Java newbie, aren't you? In that case you should get a grasp of the basics first before diving head first into complex topics such as servlets or emails. Just replace `String toAddress` with `String[] toAddresses`

Comment: yup i am new to this, its not working i have change the string to array like String [] toAddress

Comment: hey sir after doing `String[] recipients = request.getParameterValues("email-ids");` this and `String [] toAddress` this to my method , `InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };` is giving error as `The constructor InternetAddress(String[]) is undefined`

Comment: @viveksingh of course it is. You need to create a new `InternetAddress` instance for each element of the `toAddress` array. Please do yourself a favor and do some tutorials on the basics first. You're trying to run when you bare can walk - that is bound to cause problems at about every corner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [InternetAddress.parse](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method.